# Como crear un <div> con bg-img que contiene texto, y centrar texto sin flex-box

Tags: css, html5, div, background

estoy creando, para un lab una pagina donde tengo que crear un div con una img de bg y dentro un texto centrado horizontalmente y verticalmente.

```
  **<div class="topImage">
    <h1>Apple Pies</h1>
  </div>**
```

estoy usando este estilo:

```
#topImage {
  background-image: url("../images/apple-pie.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
h1 {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1, 5 rem;
  color: white;
}
```

Alguien tiene una idea?
Muchas gracias cracks

Comment: `#topImage` significa una id, pero topImage es una clase. (`.topImage`)

Answer (score 0):

`#topImage` significa una id, pero topImage es una clase. Entonces necesitas usar `.topImage`.

```css
.topImage {
  background-image: url("https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/ae6/fresh-apple-pie-1327510.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
h1 {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1, 5 rem;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topImage">
  <h1>Apple Pies</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me estaba equivocando.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes muchas maneras de hacerlo sin tener que recurrir al uso de las **cajas flexibles**. Una de ellas es hacer que el contenedor sea `position: relative` y el contenido `position: absolute`. A través de `top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` indicamos que queremos que el contenido esté a la misma distancia de los cuatro lados del contenedor.

Ponerle una altura determinada al contenido es necesario para que el `margin: auto;` pueda determinar como colocar el elemento y por último con `text-align: center;` lo centramos horizontalmente.

```css
.topImage {
  background-image: url("https://www.simplyrecipes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/apple-pie-horiz-a-1800.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1, 5 rem;
  color: red;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 50px; /*requires explicit height*/
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="topImage">
  <h1>Apple Pies</h1>
</div>
```

**Referencia:** [13 ways to vertical center](https://blog.logrocket.com/13-ways-to-vertical-center)

Comment: Muchas gracias asi funciona :-)

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa mas rustica pero valida , mas en los casos cuando el contenedor no tengo que ajustarse a otras resoluciones es usar la propiedad [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) , podes usarla aprovechando que el contenedor ya tiene declarado un alto fijo que seria el mismo valor que el alto de linea

```css
.topImage {
  background-image: url("https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/ae6/fresh-apple-pie-1327510.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
h1 {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1, 5 rem;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topImage">
  <h1>Apple Pies</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias mil por la ayuda